# JSP engine vs JDK, Servlet engine vs JRE?

Tags: java, tomcat

According to a relevant JSP/Servlet tutorial:

1. The `JSP engine` first converts a jsp file into a servlet (.java) and then compiles it into a class file (.class)

Sounds like `jsp engine = translator + compiler`.

Question #1: What is Tomcat's internal compiler? Is it JDK's javac? If not, why Tomcat needs to know `JAVA_HOME` environment variable (Java's installation root)? How are they related?

2. The `servlet engine` executes the class file

Servlet engine sounds like a runtime environment. Question #2: Is it Java's JRE? If not, why do we need to specify the JRE path during the installation of Apache Tomcat?  How is the servlet engine related JRE?

Comment: 1. it is the jasper compiler that translate jsp to java from tomcat. it then use javac to compile the .java to .class (JAVA_HOME).
2. tomcat can use JRE to run compiled class, which is the servlet java class.

Comment: If jasper compiler does translation only, and javac does the compilation, why jasper compiler is called jasper `compiler`?

Comment: good question :), It compiles .jsp file to .java, that is why it called compiler.  https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jasper/docs/api/org/apache/jasper/compiler/Compiler.html